# C# function that return instance with unknown generic type

Tags: c#, generic-type-argument

I am now implementing a function `Register()` which invoking other function `ApiReturnFactory()` inside.

```
    public ???? Register(string username)
    {
        var result = new AccountProcess().CreateAccount(username);
        return ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(result);
    }
```

`new AccountProcess().CreateAccount(username)` returns me an object like `obj<WhateverType>`.

`ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(obj)` returns me an object like `obj2<SameTypeWithWhateverType>`.

My question is the compiler have already know what type I will return in `ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(obj)` (IntelliSense do), but what should I state in the return type `????` of `Register(string username)`?

I don't want to specific a generic type for `obj` like `obj<string>`, this is not reasonable since the generic type may not always be a string. What I want is something like `obj<T>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at the `dynamic` return type?

Comment: "since the generic type may not always be a string" - either this is wrong or your code sample is missing something. `result` must have a clearly defined type that is known at compile time. If it *does* then the type is fixed and can be inserted. If it *doesn't* then there must be some other use of generics within the function that you're not showing.

Comment: Could you provide exact signatures of `CreateAccount` and `CreateInstance` methods?

Comment: @Mauro I don't want to do it in such way as the object returned from `Register()` loss its type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes you are right, actually it is always returning the same type, but is there any way to make the return object auto detect the generic type?   If I want to modify `CreateAccount()` to return other generic type in the future, then I should change the return type of `Register` too?

Comment: @mannok you dont have to change the type if it implements an interface and your return type is that interfacetype see Ehsans answer

Comment: @Mauro Thanks!    I will try to understand and run it later. If it works I will mark it as acceptable ans.

Comment: But the only way that would work *close* to what your code currently does is if `CreateAccount()` were to be changed to be generic - at which point you'd just make this method generic too `public obj2<T> Register<T>(string username)` and `var result = new AccountProcess().CreateAccount<T>(username);`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I get what you mean, but is it reasonable for me to state the generic type of the return object again when I know the generic type of the return object `ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(result)` in advance?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is for type-inference to work for method return types. That's not currently available and I would guess is unlikely to appear in a future version of the C# language since I don't see a *compelling* use-case for it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, May I know is there any alternative way to do this?   Or any better practices in my case?

Answer (score 4):

Create an interface and inherit your generic types from that interface and return that interface object back or a base class whatever is suitable in your use-case:

```
public interface IObject
{

}

public class GenericClass<SomeType> : IObject
{


}
```

and then you can return the interface object :

```
public IObject Register(string username)
{
    var obj = new AccountProcess().CreateAccount(username);
    return ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(obj);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method but seems the returned object do not have the GenericClass properties in ItelliSense list

Comment: you would need to define the common members of your generic type in interface to be accessible via reference of interface type

Comment: @Ehasn Saijad Sorry I thought I don't get what you mean. Please take a look of `ApiReturn` and `IApiReturn` at [http://imgur.com/a/PAcxX](http://imgur.com/a/PAcxX). Am I doing it your way?

Comment: from the code you have shown, you don't need interface as your whole class is generic already.

Answer (score 1):

```
public obj2<T> Register<T>(string username)
{
    var result = new AccountProcess().CreateAccount(username);
    return (obj2<T>)ApiReturnFactory.CreateInstance(result);
}
```